# C - Heap Corruption Detected when freeing array

Tags: heap-corruption

making an assignment and had to dynamically allocate an array of pointers and then free it at the end of the function.
the problem is when I free the array, it gives me a "Heap Corruption Detected" error and i cant figure out why that happens.
can anybody see something here ?
it says im writing after the end of allocated memory but i cant see why.

```
typedef struct _client
{
    char id[9];         
    char phone[12]; 
} Client;

Short_client *createShortClientArr(int n)
{
    Client *arr = (Client *)malloc(n * sizeof(Client));
    char garbage;
    garbage = getc(stdin);//for getting the '\n' from the last input
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fgets(arr[i].id, 9, stdin);
        arr[i].id[9] = '\0';
        garbage = getc(stdin);
        fgets(arr[i].phone, 12, stdin);
        arr[i].phone[12] = '\0';
        garbage = getc(stdin);
    }
free(arr);
}
```

Comment: When you free memory, Windows will also check and see if you'd written past the end of the array. Since you did, it throws this exception, to let you know you have a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you free memory, Windows will also check and see if you'd written past the end of the array. Since you did, it throws this exception, to let you know you have a bug.

```
 char phone[12];
```

This creates an array whose indecies are 0-11.

```
    arr[i].phone[12] = '\0';
```

12 is not a valid index for this array, and so this writes a `'\0'` to the `char` one past the end of the array. You have the same bug with your other array as well.